# Notation: square brackets with a unique scalar?

Tags: notation

my question is purely about notation.

I am reading papers in computer science and I see that people use the following notation $[x]$ to denote $\{1,2,\ldots,x\}$. Is that correct? Or does it mean something else?

I used to see square brackets to denote intervals...

Comment: Square brackets could mean many things, though I have not seen it mean $\{1,2,\ldots,x\}$ before (having said that, there would be nothing wrong with defining it as such). As an example, $[x]$ is sometimes used to denote the equivalence class of elements that are equivalent to $x$. Equivalence, of course, depends on the context.

Comment: Yes, a number of books and papers in the field of combinatorics use $[n]$ to represent $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ when $n$ is a positive integer.  In particular Graham and Stanley both use this notation in their books.  See in particular page 671 of Richard Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics for a partial list of notations used in his book.  If the letter $x$ is used instead, it can also be interpreted as the coefficient of $x$ in the polynomial under consideration.  Square brackets have many different uses which change depending on context.

Answer (score 1):

It is frequently used that way, both in computer science and other fields. In coding- and information theory amoong others.